# How to enable trigger over all tables that has foreign key reference to another table in oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, foreign-keys, data-consistency

In the database i have one base table, named `Organization` that most of tables has foreign key to that. assume this below ERD:

[image: Database ERD]

As you seen `Organization` table has a column named `is_enabled`. now if i want to disable the `Organization`, i should set `is_enabled` to `1`. it's very simple, but the problem is that if i want to prevent all other procedures and functions to use the disabled `Organization`, i should define `trigger` on all of the tables that has foreign key reference to `Organization` table, and this way is bad.

Is there another way to prevent all objects to use disabled `Organization`s?
also for insert or update the data, for example if i have a `Organization` with **org1** title, and if it has a `Department` with **dep1** name, after i disabled **org1**, i couldn't update **dep1** name, and this problems exists for all tables that has reference to `Organization`.

Comment: In this tables yes, but maybe on other tables exisist two or more column

Comment: Eight *hundred* tables with a foreign key reference to Organization seems like a whole lot, is what I'm trying to say. Especially eight hundred tables with only a few columns. ???

Comment: I make a simple ERD to recognize the problem, also each table have it's own columns

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by 'use'. What should happen when records referring to disabled organizations are a) changed  b) queried?

Comment: I mean that if everyone want's to insert a record, for example into Person table with the value of organization that is disabled, throw an exception and prevent actions like that

Comment: I can see no other way but using triggers for that. What's wrong with them? 
If you wanted those organizations to behave as if they didn't exist you could use Fine Grained Access Control (FGAC) - but this is not the case.

Comment: Business logic such as "you're not allowed to update a disabled organization" should not be implemented in a trigger. A better solution would be to have a procedure which you'd call to perform the desired operation, and which would make all the needed consistency checks. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop users from changing the data for disabled organisations, this should be in your code - **either in stored procedures or application code**. You could have some logic or restrictions in the user interface to prevent changes to disabled organisations (the actual implementation depends on your requirements).

The other question I have (as mentioned by Bob Jarvis) in the comments, is why do you have 800 tables with an organisation ID? This doesn't seem to be normalised.

For example, why does a person link directly to the organisation table? Could they link to the department table, which has its own link to the organisation?

Comment: By the way that you said, i should change many places in the code ether in stored procedures. but i don't want to do this, because large amount of change.
And for your question, as you in the comments, i created a simple ERD to avoid complexity in the question. actual models are the bigger and have more columns.

Comment: What are the alternatives? If a database and system is well designed then it should be easy to make the change in the right place. If it's too hard to prevent users from updating data for a disabled organisation, then you should refactor your code to make it easier to update. Short term pain now for long term gain :)